# Rails: Rendering JSON only responds with first variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to render json with my `@user` and add `"authorization": "complete"` to the response. How can I do this?

Looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example, I should be able to do this:

```
format.json { render json: @user, authorization: "complete" }
```

However, my response is only @user, and "authorization" is no where to be found.

In the Rails guide example they pass in arbitrary params such as "location" and "status". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
render json: {user: @user, authorization: "complete" }
```